# Workflow in JIRA

Tags: jira

I have an app developed for Android and iOS; both have their own JIRA projects.

I'd like to be able to create single user stories in Greenhopper and assign them to both projects, without cloning/linking like I do today.

Is there a way to do this, or a recommended approach?

Comment: how about using the same project, but different issue types?

Comment: To assign an issue to both projects sounds like you want to have a multiselect field involved somewhere. Could you use a single project and then use Components to identify the one, two or more platforms that are involved?

Comment: that necessitates the same release schedule, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you better define your end-goal, such as "If a user story incorporates iOS, it should show up in X dashboard and Y filter" or "users should be able to access X filter of related issues from story details view", you may get more concrete answers.

Maybe you have a user Story from an Android user who can't see his profile picture, so you create it in the Android project. After gathering feedback, you find out they originally uploaded an unsupported file type from his friend's iPhone. At this point, you could create an iOS issue, or story, and link it to the original Android story (you mentioned that's not optimal though), or you could add the new iOS information to the original Android ticket.

If you define the complications that these methods would create, it would be easier to offer workarounds for your specific problems. It is possible using JQL (the Jira query language) to return results from multiple projects in a single filter, and that particular filter can be reported on. You can also use labels or a custom field to report on issues across projects, and then use those JQL (filter) queries in Greenhopper/Jira Agile.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Configuring+Filters